# Pass a value via Ajax on onchange

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to understand how to pass a value from a dropdown on a onChange state. Whats the best practice for this? This is what I get so far. Seems t be working, no errors. I cant get my if/else statement to fire though, so unsure how to check what varables is being caught.

Not sure if Im on the right track - whats the best practice here?

**Form:**

```
<select id="dropdown_shop_order_language" name="wcml_shop_order_language">
 <option value="nl" selected="selected">Niederländisch</option>
 <option value="en">Englisch</option>
 <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
</select>
```

**My script so far:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('#dropdown_shop_order_language').change(function () {
    jQuery.ajax(
          {
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "post",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data:     {
            action:                         'my_action',
            "dropdown_shop_order_language": jQuery('#dropdown_shop_order_language').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
      });
 });
```

**Function:**

```
function my_enque_action( $hook ) {

    global $post;
     $postid = $post->ID;  
    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        
        if( get_post_type( $postid ) === 'shop_order' ) {  
         wp_enqueue_script( 'lang_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascripts/language.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_localize_script( 'lang_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ) );

                

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enque_action', 10, 1 );




function my_action( ) {
    $dropdown_shop_order_language = $_POST['dropdown_shop_order_language'];
    echo $dropdown_shop_order_language;
    if ( $dropdown_shop_order_language == 'en' ) {

    } elseif ( $dropdown_shop_order_language == 'nl' ) {

    } elseif ( $dropdown_shop_order_language == 'de' ) {

    } else {

    }
   echo json_encode(['responsekey' => 'responsevalue']);
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
```

Comment: `alert("language is nl");` that is where you have a problem

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I have updated the code according t the comments below, and also changed the alert to an echo but still getting the same errors.

Comment: If the code is already update you still have alert inside function my_action( ) {.. and you are still not calling wp_die/exit at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

Let's drill your issues down:

1. `code: 'invalid_json', message: 'The response is not a valid JSON response.'}` this should ring a bell, something is wrong with the answer you received from the server, not the request

This is happening on your PHP code, we will see it later down into the answer.

2. I assume that myAjax.ajaxurl has a value when the javascript code is executed
3. You are missing to tell jQuery what kind of response it should wait. Do you want to give HTML? Json? See the `dataType` attribute and give it some value
4. You ajax call is missing a value. To make Wordpress ajax work you need the correct hooks to be fired (which you did in your PHP code) but you also need a special extra POST parameter called `action`, without that value Wordpress will not process your post correctly.

So here's the code for the Ajax request:

> ```
> jQuery.ajax(
>     {
>         type:     "post",
>         url:      myAjax.ajaxurl,
>         dataType: 'json',
>         data:     {
>             action:                         'my_action',
>             "dropdown_shop_order_language": jQuery('#dropdown_shop_order_language').val()
>         },
>         success:  function (data) {
>             console.log(data);
>         }
>     });
> ```

What you give as value for the `"action"` parameter is what stands after this:

add_action( 'wp_ajax_**my_action**', 'my_action' );

The function can be any name you want, but what is after the `wp_ajax_` needs to match your action parameter that comes from jQuery

5. You php code is missing the exit call

> ```
> function my_action( ) {
>     $dropdown_shop_order_language = $_POST['dropdown_shop_order_language'];
>     echo $dropdown_shop_order_language;
>     if ( $dropdown_shop_order_language == 'en' ) {
>      alert("language is en");
>     } elseif ( my_action() == 'nl' ) {
>     alert("language is nl");
>     } elseif ( my_action() == 'de' ) {
>     alert("language is nl");
>     } else {
>     alert("language is none");
>     }
>    echo json_encode(['responsekey' => 'responsevalue']);
>     exit();
> }
> ```

see the `exit();` call, you need that to stop Wordpress execution and simply respond to the Ajax request w/o having extra output.

Sidenote: I don't think that calling `alert` in PHP will ever print anything, use echo or something else if you want to test =)

Your php code should be like this:

```
function my_action( ) {
    $dropdown_shop_order_language = $_POST['dropdown_shop_order_language'];
    if ( $dropdown_shop_order_language == 'en' ) {
     // Log in some other way, maybe file?
    } elseif ( my_action() == 'nl' ) {
       // Log in some other way, maybe file?
    } elseif ( my_action() == 'de' ) {
       // Log in some other way, maybe file?
    } else {
     // Log in some other way, maybe file?
    }
   echo json_encode(['responsekey' => 'responsevalue']);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Wordpress has its own function to "die" a script, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/ - this should preferably be used in such a context, because it does a little more than _just_ make the script die immediately, including executing filters that might have been set by other parts of the script/plugins.

Comment: Thank you - cleared up some of my thoughts. Changed to an echo - not sure what I was thinking here. So far I still get the same errors though.

Comment: Update your question with the latest code / console errors so that we can help further

Comment: @Diego Just updated it, thanks

Comment: You are still missing the "action" parameter in your jQuery Ajax call

Comment: @Diego sorry, missed to update that part. Done now.

Comment: @Jerry Do you still receive errors after all of this? if yes, update the answer with the current error please. Specify if it's in your JS console or some PHP Fatal

Comment: Answer updated with changes and current errors.

Comment: If you added the dataType: "json" thing, then you are not allowed to use echo to output standard text in PHP. Just leave the echo that does json_encode. I updated my answer

Comment: Tthank you. I dont get an error for the ajax call anymore, but still get invalid_json error. Updated my question.

Comment: At this point i suggest you to check if there's some extra output when you fire the ajax call. Any warning, notices ecc or others echo around the PHP code might interfere with your call. What we did here is correct. You need to enable debug and correct the output

Comment: Thank you. Adde da line to my script, I dont get any errors now, but havent managed to fire the if/else statement. Seems to be almost there, so could probably debug and manage to get it to work, hopefully. Thanks a lot for the explanations!